# How to label output in a Do[...] loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, labeling, procedural-programming

I have a huge `list = {l1, l2, l3, ...}`, which I want to output by labeled rows. My attempt was to

```
Do[Print["list[i]:"];Print[list[i]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Which is not working very well. **I would like to know how i can "label" every line of my output like so:**

```
list[1] = l1
list[2] = l2
list[3] = l3
...
```

Comment: If your `Do` loop only exist to create the formatted output and does nothing else, you could consider replacing it with something like `Transpose[{Defer@list /@ Range[Length@list], 
   ConstantArray["=", Length@list], list}] // Grid` or `Table[{"list[", i, "] = ", list[[i]]}, {i, Length@list}] // 
 TableForm[#, TableSpacing -> {1, 0}] &`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you had in mind?

```
Do[Print["list[", i, "] = ", list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Comment: Far easier than expected! Thanks a lot! I did not know about the comma separated chaining within `Print[expr, expr, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `StringTemplate`.

```
fmt = StringTemplate["list[``] = ``"];
Do[Print[fmt[i, lst[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[lst]}]
```

This is still ugly: it creates a cell for every call to `Print`.  You say the list is "huge" (justifying `Do`), but then you want to print it.  Hmm; perhaps it is not so huge?  If you don't mind using a bit more memory, the following is conceptually cleaner.

```
strings = MapIndexed[fmt[First@#2, #1] &, lst];
Print@StringRiffle[strings, "\n"]
```

Comment: Actually it is not that "huge" but to huge for me to type out every line by hand ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Dataset` to create an easy-to-read output of your list. `Dataset` handles very large outputs really well:

```
Dataset[AssociationThread[Range[Length[list]] -> list]]
```